# Uploading image to Parse.com with AFNetworking causing corrupt image

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, parse-platform, afnetworking-2

I am trying to upload images to Parse.com using AFNetworking 2.0.
When I download the image which has been stored on 'Parse', then the resulting file is corrupt.

By doing a diff I see that the following data has been appended to the beginning:

[image]

There is also appended 'boundry' data at the end of the file.

What am I doing wrong? Mime type?

I send the same file using 'curl' and everything is ok.

This is the code I use for sending:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[headers enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *value, BOOL *stop) {
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:value forHTTPHeaderField:key];
}];

[manager POST:@"https://api.parse.com/1/files/imagefile.jpg"
   parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
      {
          NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);

          [formData appendPartWithFileData:imgData
                                      name:@"imagefile"
                                  fileName:@"imagefile.jpg"
                                  mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
      }
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          success(operation, responseObject);
      }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          failure(operation, error);
      }
 ];
```

**UPDATE**

The following code works as expected (not multi-part, so clearly this is the problematic area):

```
NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString string];
[urlString appendString:@"https://api.parse.com/1/"];
[urlString appendFormat:@"files/imagefile.jpg"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"***********" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
[request addValue:@"***********" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
[request addValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3f)];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
NSString *fileUrl = [httpResponse allHeaderFields][@"Location"];
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you aren't using the Parse.com SDK to do this?

Comment: Yes, don't want code to be coupled to parse' sdk as we might change backend. Using rest API for everything.